# Changes to laundry room - do we need to use current plumbing code?

Tags: plumbing

We’re adding a washing machine box w/new valves, changing out some drywall, putting down a tile floor, and adding a utility sink in our laundry room.

Do we need to follow current building codes, or do we only need to follow the codes from the 1950s (when the house was built)? For example, the current drain stack is 1.5” - should we update it to 2” since we’re adding a sink to it?
My husband and I are having a difference of opinion on this….

(We live in Alabama, if that matters)

Thanks!

Comment: What does "need" mean here? Are you pulling a permit and having it inspected? Do you just want it to _work_?

Comment: @isherwood - Well, I guess I’m thinking that if we go by the code, it will work as well as it possibly can? I’m no plumber, but I’ve read the IPC and most of it seems like solid advice. Plus I’d like to sell my house in the near future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repair or renovation sets the path for what's required. Existing washer valves leak or don't work and you replace them, that's repair. But your whole package is pretty clearly renovation, as a package.

> adding a washing machine box w/new valves

If this is just replacing existing valves, that would fall under "repair. If it's "new", that's renovation.

> changing out some drywall

Fixing a hole in the wall is more repair than renovation, but tearing out drywall to replace things is renovation...

> putting down a tile floor

Screams renovation for the overall package of work, but in isolation would not (of itself) require plumbing changes. But it's not in isolation.

> **adding** a utility sink

Ding, ding, ding, ding! We have a winner! Bring it up to current code.